# Why must I press Enter twice for cin statements using Netbeans 7.3.1 and the latest MinGW toolset?

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I have recently upgraded to Netbeans 7.3.1 and have switched my compilation tools from Cygwin to MinGW, and something I noticed, is that when I build and run my project within Netbeans 7.3.1 and it runs within the Netbeans terminal, I have to press Enter twice for every cin statement I have in my code; whereas with the Cygwin tools and Netbeans 7.3, I never had to double enter within the terminal.  I also have noticed that my input no longer shows up in the terminal as it did with 7.3 and Cygwin, so I can no longer see what I have typed into the cin statement while I'm typing it, as I was able to with 7.3 and Cygwin tools.

I do not understand why I have to press enter twice in the Netbeans terminal compiled using Netbeans 7.3.1 and MinGW, whereas in Netbeans 7.3 and using Cygwin I did not have to do so; and also, why my cin input does not show up as it did in Netbeans 7.3 and Cygwin.

Does this have to do with settings for Netbeans 7.3.1?  Is this normal when using MinGW?  In my days of Visual C++ 6.0 and Windows programming in the early 2000s (2003ish), I noticed that if there was not a 'system(PAUSE)' or a 'cin' or something to catch input before the return 0 of the main() function, it would immediately close out and you couldn't even see the console; is this the same kind of problem/issue when using MinGW?

I have recently been working on creating a .h file out of the many .h files I had, for a TxtRPG engine I have decided to work on, that you may find here:

[.h and .cpp source](http://www.mindfluxproductions.com/misc/programming/FireStormRPGCode_v0.01.pdf)

At first I was concerned that the above might be the issue, but, even after making the basic C++ application in Netbeans 7.3.1 and doing a simple 'hello world' program with some cin statements, the double enter problem still remains. . .

I am concerned about the double enter because this has never happened to me ever, in all of my years of my self-taught programming, and I'm kind of a perfectionist.  If the other 'text doesn't show up as I type it' is a normal thing with the MinGW tools, I can deal with that; but this double enter has to go.

Thank you all for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project -> properties 
Go to Run
Set Console type to Standard Output